# Как вытащить баннеры с сайта

Tags: java, парсер

Задача следующая:
Нужно проанализировать сайт и скопировать все баннеры по заданному формату в отдельный файл.

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно найти баннеры в которых содержится текст "Южная Долина":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо этого, нужно найти баннеры других конкурентов.
В идеале проделать такое по нескольким сайтам аналогичной тематики.
Имеются начальные навыки Java. Как можно реализовать данную задачу? В каком направлении искать?

Comment: ...........jsoup

Comment: вы можете выделить формальные признаки банера? то бишь, что бы человек мог определить, что это банер только посмотрев на код страницы?

Comment: @Mikhail насколько я понимаю, по этим признакам можно определить баннер:

Comment: <a class="pb b-photoblock_item object-item_hover " rel="nofollow" href="http://b.irn.ru/click/?bid=20356&amp;uid=hI1KEV1I8HoGukpq0JZi&amp;site=1&amp;host_type=2&amp;page=www.irn.ru%2F&amp;col_count=1" target="_blank" style=""></a>

Comment: @Алексей, сегодня разбирался с jsoup, нашёл рабочий код, который выдёргивает абсолютно все картинки с сайта https://buddhimawijeweera.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/parsing-html-pages-with-jsoup/ Мне же нужно получить прямоугольник как на первом скрине(картинка вместе с текстом). Возможно ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека JSOUP позволяет выбирать нужные элементы на странице. Вот так можно получить все элементы `img` вложенные в `a` с указными признаками

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.irn.ru/").get();
Elements elems = doc.select("a[rel=nofollow].pb.b-photoblock_item > img");
```

Comment: за наводку с уточнениями к выборке элементов спасибо!  
С картинками более-менее прояснилось.  
Дело в том, что у них на сайте баннер как текстово-графический блок(картинка + текст).  Какие могут быть решения?

Comment: @Артём, выбирать сами `.b-photoblock_item` ?